# Good problem book in riemannian geometry with specific exersices in curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Please I'm looking for some exersices similar to this one below. I have looked in a lot of books but in vain. If some one can suggest some books or links, I would be very grateful.

---

Let $(M,\langle,\rangle)$ be a riemannian manifold equipped with th connexion of Levi-Civita $\nabla$.

1. Show that in an orthonormal frame, $\Delta(f)=\sum_{i=1}^n Hess(f)(E_i,E_i)$
2. Show that $Ric(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle R(X,E_i)Y,E_i\rangle$

Let $X$ be a Killing vector field on $M$, i.e., $$X\langle Y,Z\rangle -\langle [X,Y],Z\rangle -\langle Y,[X,Z]\rangle =0, $$
and let $f :M\to \mathbb R$ be a function defined by : $f(p)=\frac{1}{2} \langle X(p),X(p) \rangle $

1. Show that $\langle \nabla_YX,Z\rangle +\langle Y,\nabla_Z X\rangle =0.$
2. Show that for any function $g$, $\Delta(X(g))= X(\Delta(g)).$
3. Show that $\nabla f=-\nabla_XX.$
4. Show that $Hess(f)(Y,Y)=-\langle R(X,Y)X,Y\rangle +\langle \nabla _YX,\nabla _YX\rangle .$
5. Show that $\Delta(f)=-Ric(X,X)+|\nabla X|^2.$

Answer (score 2):

The following are more than what you want (The first one is contains all that you want):

- *Petersen, Peter*, [**Riemannian geometry**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-26654-1), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 171. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-26652-7/hbk; 978-3-319-26654-1/ebook). xvi, 401 p. (2016). [ZBL1220.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1417.53001).
- *Gadea, Pedro M.; Muñoz Masqué, Jaime; Mykytyuk, Ihor V.*, [**Analysis and algebra on differentiable manifolds: a workbook for students and teachers**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-5952-7), Problem Books in Mathematics. London: Springer (ISBN 978-94-007-5951-0/hbk; 978-94-007-5952-7/ebook). xxv, 617 p. (2013). [ZBL1259.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1259.53002).
- *Lee, John M.*, [**Introduction to Riemannian manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-91755-9), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 176. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-91754-2/hbk; 978-3-319-91755-9/ebook). xiii, 437 p. (2018). [ZBL1409.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1409.53001).

Comment: Thanks a lot @C.F.C I am going to check them.